# Facebook FB.logout not working in IE

Tags: django, facebook, internet-explorer, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am working on a django website which also allows users to sign in using their Facebook account. The login works fine, however I am not able to logout using Internet Explorer. The code seems to work fine on Firefox and Chrome.

Heres the code

```
function logoutFBUser()
{
    //logout user from website and Facebook and reload 
    alert ("called FB logout");
    if (FB.getAuthResponse()) 
    {
        alert ("has auth response");
        FB.logout(function(response) 
        {
            window.location.href = '/accounts/logout?next=/';
        });
        alert ("logged out of FB and redirected");
    }
    else 
    {
        alert(" no auth response");
        window.location.href = '/accounts/logout?next=/';
    }
}
```

In Firefox, I get the alert of `has auth response`, however in IE, I get the alert `no auth response`. If I only use `FB.logout` without `FB.getAuthResponse` then the function hangs when it hits `FB.logout`.

What am I missing?

Comment: You should add the IE version you're using and consider a bug report of some sort (can you actually report bugs to Facebook?). Also, this FB.getAuthResponse() is actually sending a request to Facebook, right? So it has nothing to do with Django and Python (which you've tagged it with). You're having a problem with IE and Facebook at the same time = some freaky cocktail. Consider not solving it at all.

Comment: I am using IE 8. I need to solve it, because I will have many people using it on IE. Is there any other way to implement the logout??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved this. I debugged into the javascript for FB.logout and for some reason it doesnt have the access_token which is why the call to FB.logout fails. Researching the Facebook documentation led me to this URL which I used for the logout process on my website successfully

**Logoutlink from Facebook Documentation**

https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=REDIRECT_URI&access_token=LOGGEDINUSER_ACCESS_TOKEN

Needless to say, I am using this on the serverside, so no need to use javascript any more.
Please refer Facebook Authentication documentation for more information.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Thanks for all the help